# AWS Golang SDK - How to put DeleteOnTermination on EBS volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I'm looking for a way to put on EBS volume the DeleteOnTermination bit with AWS Golang SDK.
I've tried this code but it doesn't works:

```
attach := &ec2.AttachVolumeInput{
        Device:     aws.String(*DeviceName),
        InstanceId: aws.String(*instanceID),
        VolumeId:   aws.String(*VolumeId),
    }

volumeAttach, errAttach := client.AttachVolume(attach)
if errAttach != nil {
    return errAttach
}

volumeAttach.SetDeleteOnTermination(true)
```

I've found no helpful clue in documentation and I can't find is my mistake.
Someone does have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't works"? Do you get any error messages, it does not compile?

Comment: No I haven't got error. All works fine except that DeleteOnTermination bit on volume is not set after that. I looks like the SetDeleteOnTermination method just change the state of the volumeAttach struct. I try to find a way for use this struct as argument for another method or something like that but I nothing into the documentation or I've miss this part.

Comment: DeleteOnTerminate  is a `BlockLevelMapping` setting. Have to check where in go you specify/update the mapping. It is usually when you create an instance, launch configuration, ami,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, here is the solution:

```
mappingSpecification := ec2.InstanceBlockDeviceMappingSpecification{
        DeviceName: aws.String(deviceName),
        Ebs: &ec2.EbsInstanceBlockDeviceSpecification{
            DeleteOnTermination: aws.Bool(true),
            VolumeId:            aws.String(volumeId),
        },
    }

    attributeInput := ec2.ModifyInstanceAttributeInput{
        BlockDeviceMappings: []*ec2.InstanceBlockDeviceMappingSpecification{&mappingSpecification},
        InstanceId:          instanceID,
    }

    requestModify, _ := e.client.ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest(&attributeInput)

    errorRequest := requestModify.Send()
    if errorRequest != nil {
        return errorRequest
    }
```

This code works for me.